# Has anyone experienced duplication issues when exporting large datasets to .CSV on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: export, arcgis-pro, duplication

I am working with a shapefile in ArcGIS Pro that has 3.2 million observations and about 20 columns. The .shp file is 87MB and the .dbf is just over 2GB.  I am attempting to accomplish an export.

When I export the data via the standard ArcGIS Pro instructions (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/tables/export-tables.htm), the table successfully exports as a .csv but at around row 1.6 million all the observations begin to repeat the same observation. No observations are dropped or added, and the original shapefile remains intact.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Edit: after replicating the issue in QGIS, it seems that it has trouble getting past the 1.6millionth observation, and then copies that same observation down. In QGIS, it simply halts at that 1.6millionth observation (i.e. feature count directly differs between shapefile and the resulting table).

Comment: The .shp file is 87MB and the .dbf is just over 2GB.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm) - "There is a 2 GB size limit for any shapefile component file..."

Comment: Ah - classic, should have read the documentation. I will take steps to break up and iterate the process. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke do you have any suggestions as to how I can work around this issue? Have tried several solutions to no avail...

Comment: Your shapefile may be corrupt. I f you can recreate it using a file geodatabase, you'll be able to store much larger datasets. Try exporting to a FGDB feature class first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Luke in the comments - there is a 2 GB size limit for any shapefile component file.